# ı am trying to write a sql query in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

With spring boot, I want to delete data greater than 48 hours in the
database with a sql query.

I want to delete data in database more than 48 hours.

```sql
DELETE FROM schedule WHERE date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR;
```

This query works fine in mysql, but I want to do it in spring boot.

```java
@Query("DELETE FROM schedule WHERE date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR")
```

i do it this way but i get error ('(',  or  expected, got '48')

Answer (score 2):

i think this one will be helpful,

```
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM schedule WHERE date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR", nativeQuery = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use hibernate query language(HQL) instead of native query

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: e.g. @Query(value = "delete from entity_name where date_time < NOW() - INTERVAL 48 HOUR")