# Convert sql to Jpql(Spring Boot)

Tags: sql, mysql, spring-boot, jpql

I need convert query from sql:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(BOTH '\"' FROM value) FROM game_configs,JSON_TABLE(operators,'$[*]'COLUMNS (value VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.name')) AS names;"
```

to jpql query.
Appropriate entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "game_configs")
public class GameConfig {

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(name = "operators")
    private String operators;
}
```

Comment: did yo try to use, a `@Query` with `nativeQuery = true` parameter ? [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76759925/%c4%b1-am-trying-to-write-a-sql-query-in-spring-boot/76759955#76759955)